# R new_handle function does not work properly?

Tags: r, curl

I need to run following code

```
library(curl)
user= "GEAS"
password= "878282193100310"
content = paste("username=", user, "&password=", password, sep="") 
h <- new_handle(copypostfields = content) 
handle_setheaders(h, 
                  "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
) 
handle_setopt(h, ssl_verifypeer = FALSE, ssl_verifyhost = FALSE)
```

However, this code stops at line when `new_handle` function is applied. When running this line I have following output

```
> h
<curl handle> (empty)
```

How can I make `new_handle` function work properly?

Comment: What do you mean  *stops*? Does it throw an error?

Comment: by the word stops I meant that the output of this function is (empty) and as a result, the lines following this line do not perform properly

Comment: I don't see a problem here. Your code works. The handle displays `(empty)` because that place is reversed for the URL, and you never set one. This is not a problem but a feature I suppose, as you can always set the URL later when calling `curl_fetch_*`. If you want to see those options you set, try passing this handle to `curl_fetch_echo(your_url, h)`.